# release UIImagePickerControl in Objective C & IOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I got syntax error when I tried to release UIImagePickerControl after using use buttom

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [viewsavedimage setImage: image];

 [picker release];
}
```

is [picker release]; right or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't release picker from within imagePickerController as it is a parameter. You should release it from where you call imagePickerController.
And if you use ARC (weak, strong), you don't need to do this. The memory manager does it for you.